# Excel formula to get the day difference with the condition of freeze few dates in between

Tags: excel, formula

I need the formula to count the day difference with the condition of "freeze" few days from start to end date.

Example: start date : 01-01-2021 and End date is : 28-02-2021

I want to freeze the days 14-01-2021, 15-01-2021, 16-01-2021, 17-01-2021. and then calculate the day difference.

kindly help me out to get the formula.

Comment: Look into Networkdays.Intl

Comment: How would anyone know the formula for your "few" days?

Answer (score 0):

Put the "freeze days" into an own column. This will keep them visible and editable.

Had a similar problem once and solved it with `COUNTIFS` looking if banned date is in between start and end date.

In this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kpZy.png) you see my setup:

- col C is just the difference,
- col D contains the `COUNTIFS` formula (`ZÄHLENWENNS` in german):
  `COUNTIFS($G$2:$G$18;"<="&B2;$G$2:$G$18;">="&A2)`
  (Make sure to lock the range of banned days with `$`)
- col E then is the difference minus included banned days.

Now if you add or delete banned days, your differences will change accordingly.